# Examples of $X$ such that $\pi_1(X) $ not abelian?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I've come up with [some examples to apply the Hurewicz theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54771/computing-h-1x-using-hurewicz) to compute $H_1(X)$.

This is only interesting if $\pi_1(X)$ is not abelian. The only examples of $X$ such that $\pi_1(X)$ not abelian I can come up with are $\vee_i S^1$ and $\Sigma_g$ the surface of genus $g$ for $g > 1$.

Does anyone know any other examples, preferably easy ones? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Very easy examples would be products of the ones you know already :)

Comment: your first comment: I was looking for something more interesting, yet not too difficult. : )

Comment: @gary: the Hurewicz theorem doesn't say that...

Comment: More seriously (I temporarily confused myself): Take $S^3$ identified with the unit quaternions. The quaternions $\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k$ form the quaternion group $Q$. The quotient $S^3/Q$ has fundamental group $Q$. Interesting examples also arise from knot complements (try to compute the fundamental group of the complement of the trefoil knot, for example).

Comment: @Matt: are you aware that every group is the fundamental group of some space? It's not particularly hard to find a finite $2$-complex whose fundamental group is any finitely presented group, either (start with a wedge of circles, then glue in $2$-cells corresponding to the relations), and their homology isn't difficult to compute.

Comment: @Qiaochu: No, I wasn't aware of that, thanks.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to make this a community wiki question?

Comment: @Matt: ah. Then see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36775/is-the-group-of-rational-numbers-the-fundamental-group-of-some-space .

Comment: @Qiaochu's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36775/) explains his comment in somewhat more detail and lhf gives the precise reference to Hatcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One more example: complement to any non-trivial knot in $S^3$ has non-abelian $\pi_1$.

Comment: Thank you, this is my favourite answer!!

Answer (score 4):

I am late to the party here, but take any finitely presented group, say $G=\langle x_1,\ldots , x_n: r_1,\ldots r_m \rangle$. Take a bouquet of circles embedded in 4-space and a tubular neighborhood thereof. This is a space with fund. group free of rank $n$. Now carve out a tubular neighborhood of the words represented by the relations, and sew in $D^2 \times S^2$s in their place. There is plenty of room to do this in 4-space. So you can construct a $4$-manifold with $\pi_1$ being any finitely presented group that you like.

Comment: Late to the party or not, at least you gave the first reasonable answer in this thread. In case you don't know it, there's a beautiful and (sort of) related paper by Martin Bridson, *[The geometry of the word problem](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/bridson/papers/bfs/bfs.pdf)*.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [cube with a twist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/homology-of-cube-with-a-twist)

Take the quotient space of the cube $I^3$ obtained by identifying each square face with opposite square via the right handed screw motion consisting of a translation by 1 unit perpendicular to the face, combined with a one-quarter twist of its face about it's center point.

I think it is a problem in Hatcher's book somewhere

Comment: I believe the fundamental group of this quotient ends up being precisely the $8$-element quaternion group.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the figure 8.  Using Van Kampen's theorem, you know that its fundamental group is the free product of the additive group integers with itself.  Said group is nastily non-abelian.

Comment: Matt already gave the bouquets of circles in his question :)